# Get yesterday date in Unix - KSH script

Tags: unix, ksh, hp-ux

The below command is used for getting the yerterdays date in Unix Ksh on HP UX

```
DATE_STAMP=`TZ=CST+24 date +%m/%d/%Y`
```

Can somebody let me know what does "CST + 24 date " in above command do?

Comment: If this is the same `date` command which is part of the GNU coreutils, you can get yesterdays date using `date --date=yesterday`.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim I don't see that option on HPUX.

Comment: This is not part of GNU coreutils so i cannot use that command

Comment: Oh well... was worth a shot. The HP-UX machines I worked with had GNU coreutils installed somewhere non standard. Maybe yours does too?

Comment: i tried running the command but i got "--date=yesterday:  not found"
error after execution so looks like it is not installed in my machine

Comment: Note that this command will return an correct date "only" for 99.9772 % of the cases. Expressed differently, it will fail twice a year during one hour due to the DST changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command sets the timezone to CST+24 and returns the date in that timezone.

if you are looking for a command to find out yesterday's date, you are better of using the TZ trick esp. if you are in a timezone that observes DST.

use perl one liner instead.

```
#this takes local time and substracts a day(24*60*60 seconds) and formats the time.
echo `perl -e 'use POSIX; print strftime "%m/%d/%Y%", localtime time-86400;'`
```

Just a guess on your command - since its yesterday at CST+24 timezone the command returns yesterday's date and if you use CST-24, it retunrs tomorrow's date since the date translates to tomorrows date at CST-24  timezone.

Answer (score 1):

`VARIABLE=VALUE COMMAND` means that you set the environment variable `VARIABLE` to `VALUE` but not persistent but only for the executed command `COMMAND`.

In your example that means: Execute the `date` command with the environment variable `TZ` set to `CST+24` (which is Central Standard Time plus 24 hours).

Answer (score -1):

Check out this page http://www.kodkast.com/blogs/unix-shell-scripting/how-to-get-yesterdays-date where you can find out yesterday's date as well as any other previous date in unix shell scripting.

Comment: Your answer is barely a link to another site which is not appropriate with SO. Moreover, the page you linked to doesn't apply to the question.